# How Do I Pass PictureBox and Label Through Functions?

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++-cli

I'm working in a GUI environment in Visual Studio 2012

```
void dealCard(PictureBox swag, Label swaggy)
{
    swag.Image = imageListCards->Images[deck[cardCounter].index];
    swaggy.Text = deck[cardCounter].name + " of " + deck[cardCounter].suit + ", " + deck[cardCounter].value;

    if(cardCounter == 51)
        cardCounter = 0;
    else
        cardCounter++;

}

void dealHand(PictureBox swag, PictureBox swag2, Label swaggy, Label swaggy2)
{
    dealCard(pictureBoxCard4, labelCard4);
    dealCard(pictureBoxCard5, labelCard5);
}
```

pictureBoxCard4, labelCard4 etc are already in the form that I'm working with. It's not compiling the part dealCard(pictureBoxCard4, labelCard4) or the one below

Comment: Jesse_BlackJack2::MyForm::dealCard' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox ^' to 'System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox' c:\users\jesse martinez\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\jesse_blackjack2\jesse_blackjack2\MyForm.h 1538 1 Jesse_BlackJack2

Comment: Do I have to use pointers or something to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You should edit the question to include the error, and probably add the c++-cli tag for more visibility.  I don't use managed C++, but I would assume from the error message that you're meant to pass those as handles.

Comment: You will have to learn how to use the ^ hat properly for reference types like PictureBox and Label.  There are lots of tutorials and books available for C++/CLI, you don't need our help to read them.

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables through functions you would have to use pointers.

Comment: I can't figure it out by a google search. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ The bottom mentions using pointers in functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't help because I'm using C++/CLI